# NPM install failed on Windows for running grunt

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, phantomjs

I was trying to install grunt on Windows 7. I completed the `npm install -g grunt-cli` without any error. But when I tried `npm install` in the root directory of my project I got the following errors:
[image: Screenshot of Terminal]

I'm working with the latest Node.js version. 
I am running the command prompt as administrator.
Any suggestions please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The npm registry is down at the moment. Follow the issue here:
https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/4126

Comment: Hi Nolsto, I am facing this issue since before the registry went down. I've been at it a couple of days. Is it possible that I'm facing this issue because of using Windows?

Answer (score 1):

you need to [install phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) (a headless browser which will be used for the qunit tests) on your machine first

Comment: How do I do that?
I tried the npm install phantomjs command too. But it gave the same error.

Comment: It tells me PhantomJS must be installed locally via NPM.

Comment: just see my link on how to install phantomjs (this is not a npm-module)